# Ubuntu 14.04 network manager crashes every time after login

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, crash

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu gnome 14.04 LTS. Earlier, Ubuntu 14.04 was running smoothly on my laptop. But suddenly, since yesterday Ubuntu network manager started crashing every time after login or restart with error report:

```
Sigabrt in g_assertion_message()
```

Due to this I am unable to connect to Internet on my laptop.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem on the latest `14.04` as of `03/07/2015`. Purging `urfkill` did not fix the problem, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of related bug reports on Launchpad, so this may be very difficult to solve. But if you look carefully through those bug reports and the comments on them, you may find a workaround. For instance on [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1357373) someone reports that they fixed the problem by purging the package `urfkill`.

Comment: I saw that and tried it, but it didn't stop the problem for me.