# Unity System Daemon crash after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: unity, nvidia, upgrade, 15.04

I just updated to 15.04, and I had to fix my LightDM as it wouldn't start the GUI.  I uninstalled my NVIDIA drivers and installed the dependencies for it, and I can boot into Unity now.

However now when I log in, I get an internal error for unity-settings-daemon.

I tried doing apt-get -f install, apt-get upgrade and it's not fixing any broken dependencies or anything.

I can post any logs required, if you tell me where they are found.

Comment: Title for the crash is unity-settings-daemon crashed with SIGABRT in g_assertion_message()

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1298024

seems to be a similar or the same problem, but it's from mid-2014 and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This question is [related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/533533/ubuntu-14-04-network-manager-crashes-every-time-after-login) - except that question is for **14.04**, and for network-manager, so the issue must also exist on **15.04** :-(