# How do I fix these indicator crashes?

Tags: unity, 15.10, indicator, crash

I have the following error message frenzy greeting me every time I boot up my system.

The errors seem to all have started at the same point, when I accidentally removed the current kernel while removing old kernels to try resolving a different problem... Whew... And then reinstalled it before the system reboot.

All binaries that crash are indicators or related to them, although I'm not sure all are caused by the same bug:

1. nm-applet (network-manager): SIGABRT in g_assertion_message()
2. indicator-application-service: signal 5 in g_type_create_instance()
3. indicator-sound-service: something like (1) or (2)
4. indicator-keyboard-service: something like(1) or (2)
5. unity-settings-daemon: SIGSERV in gsd_power_management_stop()

[image: Millions (actually, from 5 to 8, randomly) of error messages]

The system is fully usable after this, and indicators appear functional. However, the annoying error messages keep coming back... Even though I have checked "ignore future problems of this type" after reporting...

For reference, I keep a fully upgraded system, 15.10 now, starting from Trusty (14.04).

Any ideas how to fix this?

**[EDIT]:** This may be related to [Ubuntu 14.04 network manager crashes every time after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533533/ubuntu-14-04-network-manager-crashes-every-time-after-login)

**[EDIT2]:** Back-trace during debugging what happens to nm-applet revealed:

```
g_assertion_message("..<more info here>...
assertion failed: (manager->priv->accounts_proxy != NULL)")
at /build/glib2.0-MuyBSS/glib2.0-2.46.2/./glib/gtestutils.c:2429
```

**[EDIT3]:** This backtrace looks extremely similar to one for [this bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1343911) and [this bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1235391). Do I need to try reinstalling some packages?

Comment: It seems to me either a bad lib in `/usr/local/lib/` or bad package version from ppa. for 1st point, check output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-*/*` , for 2nd point, did you install or activate a PPA lately?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will remove these crashes, that might still be reported.

New popups after a reboot need to be investigated.

Comment: This removed the crashes for about a day, then they reappeared... Unless someone comes up with a solution, I'm going to wait until the release Xenial, hoping that the upgrade will resolve this. If that doesn't work, I'll try a fresh install.

Comment: If they are reappearing, then new crashes happend.

Comment: Sure, but they appear the same as the old ones. I have to get rid of the underlying problem, esp. since once-in-awhile Xorg crashes on me as well, and I have to reboot... All of these issues are connected in my head because they started happening after what I described. Maybe, it's related to the nvidia drivers.